# Core Data Object was written to, but never read

Tags: swift, core-data

As I try to update an existing entry in my Core Data DB, I fetch the desired item by id, change it to a new item and save in context.

However, when I fetch the object and replace it, I get the warning "Core Data Object was written to, but never read." It does make sense since I'm not really using that object, but as I understand it, just giving it a value saves it in Core Data.

```
static var current: User? {
    didSet {

        if var userInCoreData = User.get(with: current?.id), let current = current { //userInCoreData is the value with the warning
            userInCoreData = current
        }

        CoreDataManager.saveInContext()
    }
}

static func get(with id: String?) -> User? {

    guard let id = id else { return nil }

    let request: NSFetchRequest = User.fetchRequest()

    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id = %@", id)
    request.predicate = predicate

    do {
        let users = try CoreDataManager.managedContext.fetch(request)
        return users.first
    } catch let error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        return nil
    }

}
```

I want to make sure, is this the recommended process to overwrite a value in Core Data, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This section

```
        if var userInCoreData = User.get(with: current?.id), let current = current { //userInCoreData is the value with the warning
            userInCoreData = current
        }
```

seems just updating local variable `userInCoreData`, not `User` object in Core Data.

So the warning says "you fetched data from core data and set to a variable, but you set another value to the variable soon, never use the first value from core data. Is it OK?"

What you really want to do is something like this?

```
        if var userInCoreData = User.get(with: current?.id), let current = current { 
            userInCoreData.someValue = current.someValue
            userInCoreData.anotherValue = current.anotherValue
        }
```